# Application is unable to get command argument

Tags: c++, pointers, configuration, visual-studio-2017, arguments

I'm unable to get command line argument with `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, No errors occurs but when further manipulation want to happen i see that `argv[ ]` and other related variables dont have any value and says `Error reading characters of string` then an `Acces violation reading location` error happens.

This is the sample code of my issue, I had to downsize it to make it readable:

```
#include "CommonHeaders.h"

void Start(char *input)
{
  lstrcpyA(host, input); 
  // In this point i see in my Debugger "Locals/Autos" that nothing 
  // is passed to function then a "Access violation ... " happens.
  // ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Start(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I always use this `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and pass command arg with *ProjectProperties->Debugging->Command Argument* and works perfect everytime. Is it possible that proper headers aren't included or any changes in project configuration could make a conflict?

Comment: Aside: it would be better if you check that `argc > 1` before you call `Start(argv[1])` and exit gracefully with a usage message.

Comment: Why don't you add a line atop main's body saying `if (argc < 2) { std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <input>\n"; exit(1); }` - if that triggers, yes it's your VS config, but at least your program handles it gracefully.  More generally, if you are providing an argument and it crashes, we can't debug it as we're not shown the code related to `host`; I've never heard of `LstrcpyA` either but presumably that's a typo for MS's non-Standard `lstrcpyA`.  You're obliged to provide a complete compile-able program when posting here (maybe you have - is `host` in your included header?).

Comment: @TonyDelroy Thank you. I have tested your solution. The problem is definitely with Configuration file not headers or the code.

Comment: Did you perhaps set the arguments for a different target from the one you’re running? I do that all the time...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the subsystem to console `Linker -> SubSytem -> Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` and dont set an `Entry point` set the `Whole Program Optimization` to `No Whole Program Optimization` and turn `SDL check` to `off`.